# Is there anyway to highlight required fields in Codename One on Form validation

Tags: java, codenameone

Has anyone tried a jquery-ui style textfield highlighting when validating Codename One Forms and is there a way to define a required property such that I dont need to check the fields one by one for an empty String.

See a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve below:

[image: text field is highlighted in red when user tries to submit because its empty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the best way is to just set the UIID of the field to something like "Required" then style the Required UIID in the theme e.g. with a red image border.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense but is there a way to to probably define a custom property on a textfield rather than have to do a check on each of the fields one by one. I hope you get the question?

Comment: You can bind a listener to the field and do this dynamically rather than on an action but we don't have a builtin validation framework at this time. It is something we'd like to add though as we move forward.